# Nest 2.x add Analyzers to existing list of analyzers

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I migrate deprecated code from Nest 1.x to 2.x. But I encountered a problem. In 1.x I added new analyzers with this code

```
analysisDescriptor.Analyzers(
            a => a.Add(SomeAnalyzerName, new CustomAnalyzer() { ... })
        );
```

How can I add new Analyzers in Nest 2.x, which haven't Add method?

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/writing-analyzers.html#_creating_a_custom_analyzer) documentation for 2.x will help you figure it out.

Comment: @Rob it does not suit me. I already have an analysisDescriptor instance, that I receive from another method with predefined Analyzers. I want to add new custom analyzer to list of predefined analyzers

Comment: Can you change type of `analysisDescriptor ` to `CustomAnalyzerDescriptor`? Then you can just past it to Analyzers `.Analyzers(an => an.Custom("a", ca => analysisDescriptor))`.